# Android string resource - need to include '%' character

Tags: android, string

So how do I include in a string resource the '%' character?

**VALID**

```
<string name="my_string">Total discount boundary:\nmin=%1$s nmax=%2$s</string>
```

**INVALID**

```
<string name="my_string">Total discount boundary:\nmin=%1$s % nmax=%2$s %</string>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to use `%%` to get a percentage sign without being parsed as a string format character.

Comment: I get %% from %% and error from % in Android Developer Studio 23.0.2. So it seems there is no such a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding formatted="false" helped me. This

```
<string name="parser_error_convert" formatted="false">Parser error, line %d, \'%s\', cannot convert \'%s\'</string>
```

works with my strings and I expect it would help also in case of your strings. Double %% does not help because you will get %% (not %) as a result.

This problem depends on the plugin version, I am using Android Developer Studio 23.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works just fine. I use the Eclipse Android plugin, and i can add a String containing % signs without a problem. What tool do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a literal **"%"** character in your string resource, you need to escape it using another **"%"** character. Here's how you can do it:

```
 <string name="rating">Rating: %d%%</string>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<string="my_string" format="false">bla bla bla</string>
```

Comment: Care to comment your answer? How your solution solves OP problem?

Comment: Setting format="false" is incorrect here as it will cause "%1$s" to literally be printed out.